# Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test/test2.php on line 28

Tags: php, pdo

I found some code using pdo for the search engine, which is easier to read etc... and I am getting the following message when running the code.

Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in /home/ubuntu/workspace/test/test2.php on line 28

```
    <?php
      // starts a session
     session_start();

    //include files
    include 'header/header.php';
    include 'nav/navigation.php';
    include 'init.php';

    //convert string time to time
    $expires = strtotime($_POST["expires"]);
    $expires = date('Y-m-d', $expires);

    //if 
    if(isset($_POST['search'])){
    $search_string = trim($_POST['keyword']);
    if(strlen($search_string) == 0)
    {
   //The user is looking for empty string...
   //as the user may have hit search by error

    }

    $keywords = explode(" ", $_POST["search"]);
    foreach($keywords as $keyword)
    {
    $keyword = trim($keyword);
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM event WHERE (eventName LIKE ? 
    OR   eventLocation LIKE ? OR  commencing LIKE ? OR  expires LIKE ?)");
    $stmt->execute(array("%$keyword%","%$keyword%","%$keyword%","%$keyword%"));
    }

    }

   ?>
   <fieldset>
   <legend><h2>Events</h2></legend>
   <form name="search" method="post" action="<?=$PHP_SELF?>">  
   <tr> <th> <td>
       <fieldset>
         <legend>Find all events</legend>
         <input type="checkbox" name="events" value="Yes" /> All events<br />
         </fieldset>
         <legend>Find events by date</legend>
        <input type="date" name="date" min="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>" 
     max="2025-01-01" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>">

        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
     <legend>search for events</legend> 
     <form name="search" method="post" action= <?=$PHP_SELF?>>
     Keyword: <input type="text" name="keyword" /> in
     <Select NAME="field">
     <Option VALUE="eventName">Event Name</option>
     <Option VALUE="eventLocation">Event location</option>

     </Select>
     <input type="hidden" name="searching" value="yes" />
     <input type="submit" name="search" value="search" />
     </fieldset>
     </form>

    </select> </td></tr>
    <?php
    //include files
    include 'footer/footer.php';
    ?>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    </script>
    </body>
```

Comment: How do you get the $dbh variable? You should show your include files or the file where $dbh is defined.

Comment: $dh defined, is there some info how to define?

Comment: Where do you make a connection to the database  [The manual of all the strange places to look](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Or show us what is in `init.php`

Comment: $databaseName = 'localhost'; 
$username = 'root'; 
$password = ''; 
$databaseName = 'xyz'; 
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $databaseName) or exit("Unable to connect to database!");